# I am getting "Unhandled exception at 0x10005655 (glut32.dll) in glut_demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020."

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2013, glut

When i run my project in visual studio 2013 I am getting this error.
"Unhandled exception at 0x10005655 (glut32.dll) in glut_demo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000020."

the code is right here:

```
#include<GL\glut.h>


const GLsizei windowWidth = 500;
const GLsizei windowHeight = 500;

GLvoid drawScene(GLvoid)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();




    glFlush();

    //this line is modified in diff window interfaces.
    glutSwapBuffers();

}

GLvoid timerLoop(int value)
{

    glutPostOverlayRedisplay();

    glutTimerFunc(1, timerLoop, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // initialize glut
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);

    int windowID = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL CUBE demo");

    glutReshapeWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight);

    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);

    glutTimerFunc(1, timerLoop, 0);

    glutMainLoop();

    //it never reacheas here.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, that means that something - possibly in the GLUT code - is using a null pointer as a class or structure and trying to read a field from it. Can you verify that none of the arguments you're passing into GLUT calls are null? I don't know GLUT well enough to see if there's any obvious init call you're missing; I suggest you try and get a version of GLUT that you can debug into (probably just a PDB for the version you've got) and look at the stack trace to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much......i found the null argument.........and now it's working properly.

Comment: @Rafidulislam Can u point out where was the problem in your code. It too have the same problem.